# Converting multiple categorical values to numeric

Tags: r

I have a data set that have multiple categorical values in one column and I can't seems to find a way to convert them to numeric.

Zone: Identifies the general zoning classification of the sale.

```
   A    Agriculture
   C    Commercial
   FV   Floating Village Residential
   I    Industrial
   RH   Residential High Density
   RL   Residential Low Density
   RP   Residential Low Density Park 
   RM   Residential Medium Density
```

Here is my code:

```
data$Zone <- as.numeric(factor(data$Zone))
```

After I done that R will change the values into 1,2,3,4,5 etc.
If that's the case how one I know which number is referring to the orginal categorical values?

Comment: When you `factor(data$Zone)` R by default set the levels based on alphabetical order. But you can change it or to be safe, specify the levels by `data$Zone <- factor(data$Zone, levels = c("A", "C", "FV", ...))`. Then when you `as.numeric()` the `data$Zone`, `A` will be 1, `C` will be 2 and so on and so forth.

Comment: @Ben Toh Can you make that an answer we can upvote and the OP can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `factor(data$Zone)`, R by default set the levels based on alphabetical order.

But you can change it or to be safe, specify the levels by

```
data$Zone <- factor(data$Zone, levels = c("A", "C", "I", "FV", ...))
```

Then when you `as.numeric()` the `data$Zone`, A will be 1, C will be 2, I will be 3, FV will be 4 and so on and so forth.